# CSS grid auto expand

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I created a 12 column grid using the CSS grid. However, now I'm stuck with auto width (Auto expand until the end) class. Can anyone tell me is there any way or workaround to achieve it?

```css
.box {background-color: #20262e; color: #fff; padding: 2rem;}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.col-6 {
    grid-column-end: span 6;
}

.col-2 {
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.col {
  background-color: red !important;
    /*  ??? */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box col-6">Parent A</div>
  <div class="box col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box col-6">Child A</div>
      <div class="box col-6">Child B</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box col-2">A</div>
  <div class="box col">AUTO FILL</div>
  <div class="box col-2">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this a flexbox job, you cannot do this with CSS grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Temani Afif said in comments - this is a work for `flex`.

### Using fixed `span`, like `col-8`

```css
.box {background-color: #20262e; color: #fff; padding: 2rem;}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.col-6 {
    grid-column-end: span 6;
}

.col-2 {
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.col-8 {
  background-color: red !important;
  grid-column-end: span 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box col-6">Parent A</div>
  <div class="box col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box col-6">Child A</div>
      <div class="box col-6">Child B</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box col-2">A</div>
  <div class="box col-8">AUTO FILL</div>
  <div class="box col-2">B</div>
</div>
```

### Using `flex`

Now it's like [Bootstrap 4 Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Used `flex-grow: 1;` for auto width flex element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #20262e;
  background-clip: content-box;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 0 15px 30px 15px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-6 {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.col-2 {
  flex: 0 0 16.66667%;
  max-width: 16.66667%;
}

.col {
  background-color: red !important;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-6">Parent A</div>
    <div class="box col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="box col-6">Child A</div>
        <div class="box col-6">Child B</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box col-2">A</div>
    <div class="box col">AUTO FILL</div>
    <div class="box col-2">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```